# How can I set up a professional Stack Overflow account?

Tags: discussion

I want to set up a professional **Stack Overflow account**, and I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Professional" Stack Overflow account. Or rather, there should be no such thing as an unprofessional Stack Overflow account.

Comment: A professional account means one simple thing: should you print it out and take it to a job interview, would you be embarrassed or think it will prevent you from landing a job? If the answer is yes to either of these questions, it is not professional.

Comment: On the off chance that by a professional account you mean a business account, you probably want [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) or [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise).

Comment: What is "a professional Stack Overflow account"?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just start by completing your public profile: set a profile picture and write something about who you are, some of your best project, what technologies you're strong in...

Let's say that your professional account should just looks like the professional yourself.